# insertar de dos tablas relacionadas a una

Tags: c#, mysql, phpmyadmin

Hola buenas tardes a todos, junto con saludarlos queria ver si me pueden orientar en lo siguiente: tenga una tabla cuentas con un idCuenta autoincremental, un campo idRegistro y un usuario y clave, esta tabla sera para crear cuentas de usuario.

El campo idRegistro es llave primaria en dos tablas diferentes (funcionario y profesional) y aca es donde me viene el problema: cuando trato de insertar una cuenta, indiferente si es un funcionario o profesional, me arroja el error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

las pruebas estan hechas con idRegistro que estan en la bd, asi que no es un tema de datos errados, creo que algo logico esta mal, pero no me doy cuenta cual puede ser la pifia.

Saludos a todos, gracias desde ya

Comment: El error esta claro en el mensaje, tu llave foránea es el problema, tal vez tu tabla **profesional** no tenga registros, u otro caso, revisa los registros de la base de datos, has la inserción primero en el gestor de la bd, después de probar que el código sql funciona bien ya ahí vas a  probarlo en la aplicación.

Comment: hola Jorge, gracias por tu tiempo, si borro una de las relaciones, inserta bien, con las dos relaciones, ahi ya falla, la prueba la hago en phpmyadmin no desde el aplicativo en c#...y cuando voy a hacer el insert, solo me muestra el idRegistro de una de las tablas

Comment: Podrías compartir tu diagrama de base de datos?

Comment: aca esta el diagrama jorge: http://es.tinypic.com/r/b4cnjo/9

Comment: No encuentro tu tabla cuentas, sería  bueno que pongas sólo las tablas en cuestión para verificar, hazlo aquí con la opción de editar.

Comment: las 3 tablas involucradas son estas: http://es.tinypic.com/r/o8ufj7/9

Comment: Identificar tus tablas es difícil, dos de ellas tienen como id el mismo nombre **idregistro** , solo pones en la tabla login 'una' llave foránea, no entiendo la lógica que estas empleando, tal vez repasar un poco de integridad referencial te haría bien, sino guíate por bds como northwind.

Comment: a eso iba jorge, debido a que no puedo hacer 2 formularios de inicio de sesion diferentes (debo usar el mismo para todos los inicios de sesion, ya sea funcionario o profesional) me decidi a usar la tabla LOGIN como base para las cuentas de usuario, ahora, tendre que añadir un idRegistro mas en la tabla LOGIN como llave foranea de la tabla profesional? ahi tengo la duda

Comment: funcionario y profesional son dos tipos de usuarios distintos? yo crearía una tabla de users y una de perfil de esa forma puedes tener todos los tipos de usuarios que necesites con los campos que necesites. en users tendrías la información inherente al login de usuario y en el perfil la información especifica mas el tipo de usuario. Si el id especifico es autoincremento primero tendrías que agregar a su tabla principal la que autoincrementa y luego a la tabla con la clave foranea, en este caso deberias insertar la data en "profesional" o "funcionario" y luego en login con el id que te devuelva

Comment: hola Carol, si son dos tipos de usuarios diferentes...el login debe ser el tipico usuario, contraseña y un perfil, en base a ese perfil se bloquearan algunos menus en el formulario...

Comment: puedes mejorar tu diseño de base de datos agregando un rol y una tabla de roles de esa manera manejas mucho mejor la vista de menus y pagina y puedes agregar muchos mas tipos de usuarios en caso de ser necesario mas adelante las tablas solo para los usuarios y permisos serian: users, profiles, roles, roles_users con eso tienes un mejor diseño y se te facilita mucho tu código, en cuanto a tu error primero debes agregar en la tabla principal luego con el retorno de el id que te debería dar el insert agregar en la tabla con clave foranea

Comment: finalmente me decante por hacer una tabla login aparte para la tabla profesioanles, los insert ya funcionan, ahora en el formulario de login añadi un combo que permite seleccionar el perfil y en base a esa eleccion hacer login como profesional o como funcionario, abrire otra pregunta porque tengo un dramita con el ingreso jeje, gracias a todos